# WP_Query get posts where post_name is empty

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field

I want to get all the posts for which the post_name(slug) is not set/empty as well as a meta_key does not exist.

```
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'books',
    'name'                   => '',
    'post_status'            => array('publish, draft'),
    'posts_per_page'         => -1,
    'meta_query'             => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'book_isbn_id',
            'value'     => 'dummy',
            'compare'   => 'NOT EXISTS',
            'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
echo $query->request;
```

It seems that `'name' = ''` or `'name' = ' '` is completely ignored from what I see from `echo $query->request`.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: You can run it excluding the `meta_query` to check whether it gives you any result or not. Then you can add the `meta_query` to further filter out the result. In the `meta_query`, you have mentioned a string value but the `type` is `NUMERIC`. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes I tried it without the meta_query and the results are same. And yes the meta_value is required and can be anything as there is a bug in the NOT EXISTS compare type. See [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23268)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'books',
    'name'                   => '',
    'post_status'            => array('publish, draft'),
    'posts_per_page'         => -1,
    'meta_query'             => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'book_isbn_id',
            'value'     => 'dummy',
            'compare'   => 'NOT EXISTS',
            'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
        ),
    ),
);

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'custom_posts_where' );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
echo $query->request;
```

where

```
function custom_posts_where( $where )
{
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    if( FALSE === strpos( $where, 'post_name' ) )
    {
        $where .= sprintf( " AND %s.post_name = '' ", $GLOBALS['wpdb']->posts );
    }
    return $where;
}
```

to search for empty post names.

Answer (score 0):

Posts name will never be empty as it is automatically set when you set the title. or if title is left blank then your post_name will be your post id. So your query will never return any results unless you've hacked the wordpress core...

Comment: Not the answer I am looking for. In my case, I have custom posts posted programmatically with the post_name empty.

Comment: can you post the code in pastebin or somewhere else to be more specific to answer your questions